# Dlink DIR 600M firmware decompile issues

Tags: firmware, decompile, embedded

How to decompile the CGI & ROM files from the firmware bin? I am able to extract the HTML files using binwalk but the router OS and CGI files are missing.

*NOTE: Its not the same as DIR 600*

[Heres a link](ftp://support.dlink.co.in/firmware/DIR/DIR-600M-Hathway/DIR-600M_C1_Hathway.zip) to the firmware image.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that either A), this update is only for a select set of files, or B) the CGI backends for HTTP requests are handled by a compiled program (ref: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html)

Answer (score -1):

Not read yet but try these two links, may be it'll helps.

http://www.devttys0.com/2011/08/extracting-non-standard-squashfs-images/
http://www.dailysecurity.net/2014/09/08/dlink-dir655-rev-b-firmware-reverse-engineering-part-1/

Comment: I have tried both methods already but I didn't find any SquashFs image or Linux header in this img. I did extract the .img using binwalk but all i get is a bunch of HTML headers / footers / copyrights